# Getting a promise instead the data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, es6-promise

I'm trying to get a  kind of getter methos using promises , it's working but I get the promise on the return instead of the data , I'm not sure about what is wrong on the code

```
function _get_username(){
    var user_promise = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
            url:'/get_username',
        }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXhr){
            console.log(data);
           resolve(data);
        }).fail( function(err){
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}

async function get_username(){
    try{
        var username = await _get_username();
    }catch(err){
        Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            text: err.message,
          })
    }
    
    return username;
}


console.log(get_username());
```

Comment: async functions return a Promise - that's what they are designed to do

Comment: oh, and `_get_username` won't return anything useful, in fact your code won't even wait for that ajax to start let alone finish

Comment: `_get_username` has no `return` statement, so it returns `undefined` and not the promise you assign to `user_promise`

Comment: You're using the nested promise anti-pattern. `$.ajax()` returns a thennable object, you can just use that instead of wrapping it in *another* promise.